# How to write dataframe into a hive table which is in kerberos authorized server without using spark?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, hive

How to write dataframe into a hive table which is in kerberos authorized server

Comment: What kind of file format for that table - CSV, JSON, AVRO, Parquet, ORC?

Comment: Csv format will do..

Comment: About compatibility issues when writing Parquet files for Presto or Spark (which in turn are "mostly" compatible with Hive)  https://medium.com/when-i-work-data/por-que-parquet-2a3ec42141c6

Comment: Our spark is a older version so can u give me a other way